# Why does the return value type of C's sizeof vary with context?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char c;

    int charSize = sizeof(c);            // Here it is an int

    printf("char: %lu\n", sizeof(c));    // Here it is an unsigned long
    printf("char: %i\n", charSize);
}
```

Compiling and running the above outputs:

```
char: 1
char: 1
```

If I use `%i` as placeholder instead of `%lu`, it throws a compilation error.

What is the cause of this behavior?

Compile flags:

`clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wshadow    sizeof.c  -lcs50 -lm -o sizeof`

Comment: No, it doesn't. It is always `size_t` unless the compiler doesn't conform to the standard.

Comment: Using incorrect format specifier invokes *undefined behavior*, and it happened to emit compile error in one case and unfortunately it happened not to emit compile error in another case. The correct format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`.

Comment: If you don't have the `%zu` format specifier you must cast the result of `sizeof` if you are supplying it to `printf`. Many compilers do not match the format specs with the arguments for `printf` - they just believe what you tell it.

Comment: @MikeCAT Except for MSVC, where it's `"%Iu"`. Hurray, Microsoft!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator always yields a result of type `size_t`  (which is an implementation-defined unsigned integral type).

However, a `size_t` can be converted to other integral types, as happens in the initialisation of `charSize`  (i.e. `sizeof` yields a `size_t`, and that is converted to an `int` to initialise `charSize`).

Such conversions, and their limitations (e.g. what is well-defined or not if the result being converted cannot be stored in the resultant type) are described by the standard.

The statement

```
printf("char: %lu\n", sizeof(c));    // Here it is an unsigned long
```

formally has undefined behaviour since `sizeof` is not required to produce a result of type `unsigned long`, and `printf()` exhibits undefined behaviour if a value being output is not of the type specified in the format string.   It is true that `size_t` and `unsigned long` are equivalent on some implementations (i.e. compilers) and that statement will behave appropriately then.   However, there are other implementations for which `size_t` and `unsigned long` are different types.